# Was or is? Confusion

Tags: tenses

My question is for example when closing a call with a customer which is the proper way?
"Once again my **was** (name), have a great day!" or "Once again my **is** (name), have a great day!"

need this cleared up lol

Comment: Unless it's changed during the call it still "is".

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you would use the word **is**, as your name hasn't changed. (This is in the present tense and therefore must be "is", not "was", which would be in the past tense.)

Comment: Ok so my argument was that since I already spoke to the customer and it is past tense so to let them know as a reminder my name WAS does that make sense or no matter what it's still IS?

Comment: But your name specifically didn't change; if it did, though, then it would be was

Comment: Oh okay well thank you now that I got the correct answer I appreciate it!